# Using metafizzy isotope to create a custom center alignment of items in rows, is this possible?

Tags: alignment, customization, center, jquery-isotope

I have a design with a custom layout for a lot of images which looks simple but development wise isn't. What I want to do is use Isotope to align and filter all of the images, but the alignment is custom. The images should always center within their container and the maximum number of items in a row alternates, so it goes Row 1 has maximum of 3 images, Row 2 has a maximum of 2 images, repeat this order for all other rows. I included a link to a quick diagram of how this will play out with different amounts of images. I'm not sure how or if Isotope can center these images no matter what the total number of them is per row. Any thoughts on this one?

[image: Diagram link]

Answer (score 0):

No, for something like this, you better look into algorithms related to [circle packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) and [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing). You find good algorithms via MATLAB and Mathematica.